# MySQL - Dynamic statement via UDF in triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers, user-defined-functions

in order to bypass the lack of prepared statement in triggers, I am giving a try at the idea to write a UDF that executes its agrument.

The udf relies on the MySQL C api and uses a specific user with limited rigths.

```
#include "string"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "mysql.h"
#include <sstream>

extern "C" my_bool execsql_init(UDF_INIT* initid, UDF_ARGS* args, char* msg) {
        if (args->arg_count != 1) {
                memcpy(msg, "Missing message argument.", 26);
                return 1;
        }
        if (args->arg_type[0] != STRING_RESULT) {
                args->arg_type[0] = STRING_RESULT;
        }
        return 0;
}

char* setError(unsigned long* length, std::string message) {
        *length = message.size();
        return (char*)message.c_str();
}

extern "C" char* execsql(UDF_INIT* initid, UDF_ARGS* args, char* result, unsigned long* length, my_bool* is_null, my_bool* error) {
        MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);
        if (con == NULL) {
                return setError(length, "Erreur d'initialisation");
        }

        if (mysql_real_connect(con, "172.31.72.6", "execsqluser", "qwerty", "nvannuaire", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL) {
                mysql_close(con);
                return setError(length, "Erreur de connexion");
        }

        mysql_query(con, "use nvannuaire;");

        if (mysql_query(con, args->args[0])) {
                std::ostringstream ss;
                ss << mysql_errno(con) << ": " << mysql_error(con);
                std::string error = ss.str();
                return setError(length, (char*)error.c_str());
                mysql_close(con);
        }

        mysql_close(con);

        std::string retour = "ok !";
        *length = retour.size();
        return (char*)retour.c_str();

}
```

This seems to work well, but a problem occures.
After calling the execsql(), nothing else happens.
The statement is executed, but not those that come next in the stored procedure.

```
SELECT execsql(statement_requete) INTO i_retour FROM t_requete WHERE id_requete = a_id_requete;

-- test la valeur de retour
IF i_retour != 'ok !' THEN
    -- si pas ok, on renseigne l'erreur via update
    UPDATE t_requete SET erreur_requete = i_retour WHERE id_requete = a_id_requete;
ELSE
    -- si == 'ok !', on delete
    DELETE FROM t_requete WHERE id_requete = a_id_requete;
END IF;
```

dbForge Studio raises a «Got timeout reading communication packets».

Here is the file mysql.log :

```
.
.
.
140709 10:33:21  2020 Init DB   nvannuaire
                 2020 Query     select * from ta_avancement order by id_tache desc limit 0, 20
140709 10:33:22  2020 Query     select * from t_tache order by id_tache desc limit 0, 20
                 2020 Query     SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `nvannuaire` LIKE 't_tache'
                 2020 Query     SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_increment%'
                 2020 Query     select * from t_requete order by id_evenement desc limit 0, 20
                 2020 Query     SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `nvannuaire` LIKE 't_requete'
                 2020 Query     SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_increment%'
                 2020 Query     select * from t_comptenovell where id_comptenovell = 115 limit 0,1000
                 2020 Query     SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `nvannuaire` LIKE 't_comptenovell'
                 2020 Query     SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_increment%'
                 2020 Query     CALL pr_si_avancement_avancer(55, 115, 2)
                 2029 Connect   execsqluser@172.31.72.6 on nvannuaire
                 2029 Query     use nvannuaire
                 2029 Query     UPDATE t_comptenovell SET login_comptenovell = "Test" WHERE id_comptenovell = 115



140709 10:33:52  2020 Init DB   annuaire
140709 10:33:58  2020 Init DB   nvannuaire
                 2020 Query     select * from ta_avancement order by id_tache desc limit 0, 20
                 2020 Query     select * from t_tache order by id_tache desc limit 0, 20
.
.
.
```

Edit: When the execsql function is called directly, there is no error. It only occurs when the function is called inside a trigger.

Edit 2: The storage engine is InnoDB.

Statements stored in t_requete never apply on the t_requete table, but on other tables.

And after further investigation, it seems that if the statement stored in t_requete contains some SQL syntax error, there is no timeout and all the procedure is executed succesfully (it stores the error in the erreur_requete of t_requete table).
So the problem only seems to occure when the executed statement contains no error and when it is executed inside a trigger.

In this test case, the trigger is AFTER UPDATE ON TABLE A. The statement is stored in table B, and it executes an update on table C.

Any idea why this error happens and how to solve it ?

Comment: Error seems to be a timeout. Is the MySQL server IP posted a real one?

Comment: Yes it is. I forgot to mention, when the execsql function is called directly, there is no timeout error. It only occurs when the function is called inside a trigger.

Comment: Does the statement you're executing via `execsql()` actually do something to the `t_requete` table?  It seems like there's some potential for trouble there, if it does.  MyISAM? InnoDB?

Comment: No, it desn't. The t_requete table only stores statements that need to be executed later. Those statements don't modify the t_requete table but apply to other tables.
The storage engine is InnoDB.